# Inserting Values into a Multilevel Index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe as shown:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['batch1', 'batch2','batch3', 'batch4', 'batch5'], ['quiz1', 'quiz2']])
cols=['noofpresent', 'lesserthan50', 'between50and60', 'between60and70', 'between70and80', 'greaterthan80']
statdf = pd.DataFrame('-', idx, cols)
statdf
```

[image: Dataframe Created (statdf)]

```
statdf.loc['quiz1', 'noofpresent'] = qdf1.b4ispresent.count()
statdf.loc['quiz2', 'noofpresent'] = qdf2.b4ispresent.count()
statdf.noopresent = qdf1.b4ispresent.count()
statdf.noopresent = qdf2.b4ispresent.count()
statdf
```

Then I made some calculations. I now want to append that specific calculation  of the figures '50' and '53' in column 'noofpresent' in '**batch4**', 'quiz1' and 'quiz2' respectively. But instead this happened...

[image: dataframe after insertion]

How can I insert my data into the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can index it like this.

`statdf.loc['batch4','quiz1']['noofpresent'] = qdf1.b4ispresent.count()
statdf.loc['batch4','quiz2']['noofpresent'] =qdf2.b4ispresent.count()`